# ordem em que WebApp.connectHandlers.use é avaliado

Tags: meteor

Numa aplicação de teste, tenho vários registros de dns apontando para ela, e tenho uma pasta onde guardo códigos específicos para cada origem.

O que pretendo é evitar a possibilidade de ser requisitada algum conteúdo de um site por outro, mas o problema é que todas as consultas para os elementos internos do Meteor são avaliados primeiro.

Ex:

```
/imports/@/bulica.local/index.js
/imports/@/caneco.local/index.js
/imports/@/192.168.0.1/index.js
```

e em /server/index.js logo nas primeiras instruções:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/imports/@/', (req, res, next) => {
  //  aqui vai minha lógica que compara
  //  req._parsedUrl.pathname com req.headers['x-forwarded-server'] 
});
```

A questão é que é possível um dominio acessar codigo de outro pela url, porque o Meteor avalia sempre o que existe em WebApp.clientPrograms['web.browser'] antes de tudo, entregando o arquivo. Essa minha lógica só é processada se a url não casar com nada que o Meteor já tenha "compilado"

Como resolver isso? Eu não tenho a menor idéia de como fazer isso no Apache, que também me ocorreu

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei.

No Meteor existe uma outra instância do connect da que não está na documentação que é processada antes do código criado pelo desenvolvedor. É a **WebAppInternals** ficando assim:

`WebAppInternals.connectHandlers.use` ...

de resto é igual